# Is it possible to get container OS logs from Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run

I'm using google cloud run. I run container with simple Flask+gunicorn app that starts heavy computation.

Sometimes it fails

```
Application exec likely failed
terminated: Application failed to start: not available
```

I'm 100% confident it's not related to google cloud run timeouts or Flask + gunicorn timeouts.

I've added hooks for gunicorn: worker_exit, worker_abort, worker_int, on_exit. Mentioned hooks are not invoked.

Exactly the same operation works well locally. I can reproduce it at cloud run only.

Seems like something crashes at cloud run and just kills my python process completely.
Is there any chance to debug it?

Maybe I can stream tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}  somehow in parallel to logs?

The idea is to understand what kills app.

UPD:
I've managed to get a bit more logs

```
Default
[INFO] Handling signal: term
Caught SIGTERM signal.Caught SIGTERM signal.
```

What is the right way to find what (and why) sends SIGTERM to my python process?

Comment: Have you checked Cloud Logging? Stdout/err should be logged there and would help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I've quoted two log lines. That's all I see before app crash

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest setting up Cloud Logging with your Cloud Run instance. You can easily do so by following this documentation which shows how to attach Cloud Logging to the Python root logger. This will allow you to have more control over the logs that appear for your Cloud Run application.

[Setting Up Cloud Logging for Python](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python)

Also in setting up Cloud Logging it should allow Cloud Run to pick up automatically any logs under the `var/log` directory as well as any syslogs (`dev/log`).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I don't fully follow the advice, can't find how to make it work for google cloud run. It's not a problem to ssh to VM instance, the problem is to get longs from google cloud run container. It has only HTTPS url as entry point.